# two dimensional extension of the Fourier transform of $|x|^\alpha$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I know the Fourier transform pair
\begin{equation}
|x|^\alpha \leftrightarrow -2\sin(\pi\alpha/2)\Gamma(1+\alpha)|\omega|^{-1-\alpha}
\end{equation}

Can this formula be extended to two dimensional situation?

What is the Fourier transform of
$|\mathbf{x}|^\alpha$($|\mathbf{x}|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$) ?

Thanks in advance